# Moodle Integration with a PHP project of mine

Tags: php, moodle

I've been developing a project using php that my students use to take quizes (that moodle can't do itself) Now I would like to integrate moodle and my project such that my project authenticates against moodle users and reports grades into a courses gradebook. I've so far been authenticating using direct database reading but I'm very hesitant to do writes to the moodle database. I'm also aware of LTI; I am open to using it but the human readable documentation and any samples are impossible to find. If you could provide me a sample or documentation thats less theory and more applicable for LTI it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation I've found for LTI is mostly about the development of the project and completely avoids how to implement it as a developer.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want your existing moodle users to be able to login to this other project using their moodle credentials? or the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to use the Web Services API. You need to setup a web service first, see [Using web services](http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Using_web_services). The entire API documentation is available on your Moodle site via **Administration > Plugins > Web services > API Documentation**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use moodle's External Tool, which is created precisely for this kind of uses. External tool uses LTI in the background to send user, course, role etc information to an external application and the external application can even send back scores to moodle if configured as a quiz.

Check out : https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/External_tool

You will also have to make your quiz taking app, an LTI provider. 
This open source package is out of the box package to create LTI provider in ruby - https://github.com/instructure/ims-lti
There are similar tools in other languages too, but this one is the most polished one.